# How to send data from service to receiver

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, service

I have the following projects and classes (in C#):

> **IMyService**

```
public interface IMyService
{
    void OnKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs keyPressedArgs);
}
```

> **MyService** (references **IMyService**)

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public void OnKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs keyPressedArgs)
    {
        // UNSURE WHAT TO PUT HERE     
    }
}
```

> **Receiver** (references **IMyService** and **MyService**)

```
public partial class Receiver : IMyService
{
    public static MyService Service; // initialized elsewhere

    public void OnKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs keyPressedArgs)
    {
        // Updates xaml UI here
        ...
    }
}
```

Other classes:

- ReceiverView.MainWindow.xaml
- ReceiverLogic.cs

> **Sender** (references **IMyService**, **MyService**, and **Receiver**)

```
public partial class Sender
{
    public MyService Service;

public Sender(ReceiverViewMainWindow window)
{
    MainWindow = window;
    MainWindow.Loaded += MainWindowOnLoaded;
}

private void MainWindowOnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    // Connects to the service
    ...
    Service = // connects here
    ...

    KeyboardListener = new LowLevelKeyboardListener();
    KeyboardListener.OnKeyPressed += OnKeyPressed;
    KeyboardListener.HookKeyboard();
}

public void OnKeyPressed(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Service.OnKeyPressed(sender, args);
}
```

**Updated:**

Sender will be run on PC #1. Receiver will be run on PC #2. My goal is to send keystrokes collected from PC #1 (sender) to PC #2 (receiver) via a service.

I know that to send keystrokes from PC #1 (sender) to the service, I just have to use the sender's OnKeyPressed() method to call the OnKeyPressed() method of the MyService instance created in the receiver. However, **I do not know how to then send the keystrokes from the OnKeyPressed() method in to the receiver to the ReceiverLogic.cs. If I try to add a reference in MyService to Receiver, I get a circular reference error since Receiver references MyService.

How do I access the keystroke data received in the receiver's service within the receiver? I want to use the data to update the receiver's UI, etc. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add Code? Then it's easier to understand your problem.

Comment: @Nikolaus I added code. I hope that helps to understand my problem. I am trying to get the data out of the service (the instance of MyService within Receiver) so that I can use it to update Receiver's UI. But, I do not know how I can send the data without being able to refer to Receiver in MyService.

Comment: Usually, you pass arguments with your EventArgs aren't you? Maybe you can modify them.